# confused about mysql read performance limit vs betweenAnd

Tags: mysql

For getting the same dataset, the following two SQLs took different time:

```
1, Select * from user where id between 100,000 and 200,000. (took 0.05 second)
2, Select * from user oder by id ASC limit 100,000,100,000. (took 3 seconds)
Note: the id is primary key.
```

Why the second sql so slow, I think the id is primary key, so the sorting should be very fast, even mysql did not need to sort it because the primary key already sorted. It just need to directly seek to the right position in B+tree's leaf nodes. The time should be O(1).
I supposed the two sql should be same speed.

```
Edits:
I tried to use explain on the above two SQLs. But I still can not understand 
why mysql doesn't treat limit as a range query(it's already sorted).
I guess I may say:"Mysql is not a smart engine, it's kind of old!"
```

Comment: the first  can  use index .. on primary key  the second  no

Comment: `EXPLAIN` both queries and you'll get a good indication

Comment: Explain is a general idea. I wouldn't bank too much on it.